# Data not Displaying correctly while using JqGrid Grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to show data in group using jqGrid. It creates multiple group for same name.
Below is My Code

```js
jQuery("#jqGridManage").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: Projectdata,
        colNames: ['Action', 'Opportunity Id', 'Salesforce Opportunity ID', 'Project Name (Opportunity Name)', 'Project Type', 'Type Of Revenue', 'Milestone Description', 'Amount', 'PO Number', 'PO Amount', 'Close Date', 'Assigned To',
                    'Business Unit', 'Product', 'Channel Name', 'Sales Person', 'Vertical', 'Customer Name', 'Customer Contact','Region'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'actionBtn', search: false, frozen: true, width: 200, align: 'center'},
            { name: 'OpportunityID', index: 'id', frozen: true },//, cellattr: arrtSetting
            { name: 'SalesforceOpportunityId', index: 'invdate', frozen: true },
            { name: 'OpportunityName', index: 'name', frozen: true },
            { name: 'ProjectTypeLongName', index: 'amount', frozen: true },
            { name: 'ProjectTypeChildName', index: 'tax', frozen: true },
            { name: 'ChannelName', index: 'total', frozen: true },
            { name: 'Amount', index: 'amount' },
            { name: 'PONumber', index: 'closedate' },
            { name: 'POAllocatedAmount', index: 'closedate' },
            { name: 'CloseDate', index: 'closedate' },
            { name: 'AssignedTo', index: 'note' },
            { name: 'BusinessUnit', index: 'note' },
            { name: 'Product', index: 'product' },
            { name: 'Channel Name', index: 'stage' },
            { name: 'SalesPerson', index: 'salesperson' },
            { name: 'Vertical', index: 'vertical' },
            { name: 'CustomerName', index: 'customername' },
            { name: 'CustomerContactNumber', index: 'currency' },
            { name: 'Region', index: 'amountexpected' }
        ],
        shrinkToFit: false,
        pager: "#jqGridPagerManage",
        viewrecords: true,
        autowidth: true,
        height: 450,
        sortname: "OpportunityID",
        grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ["OpportunityID"],
            groupColumnShow: [true, true],
            groupCollapse: false,
            groupDataSorted: true
        },
        resizeStop: function () {
            resizeColumnHeader.call(this);
            fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
            fixGboxHeight.call(this);
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            var ids = $("#jqGridManage").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var rowId = ids[i],
                // statusId = $("#list").jqGrid ('getCell', rowId, 'statusId'),
                // activeBtn = "";
                // if (statusId == 0) { // Inactive
                        activeBtn = "<button class='ManageEditBtn ManageEdit'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</button> <button class='ManageEdit ManageCreate'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Create Invoice</button>";
                //"onclick='publish(" + rowId + ")' />";
                // }
                jQuery("#jqGridManage").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, { actionBtn: activeBtn });


            }
        },
    })
```

In my code data coming from backend. I am grouping by OpportunityID; there are 4 opprtunity id's but each group is showing multiple times. Below is My screenshow for reference.
[image]

I have referred other same questions also but that are not helpful. Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <=4.7?

Comment: I am using Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.3.1 - 2018-03-12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colModel`, which you use have many inconsistencies. You should **remove** of `index` properties. If you use `index` in combination with `datatype: "local"`, then the value of `index` property should corresponds the `name` property or to reference `name` of another column of `colModel`. The best choice is not using any `index` property at all.

Additionally you have to fix the name of `Channel Name` column. The value of `name` property will be used for building ids of some internal elements on the HTML page and HTML5 don't allow the usage of spaces in id.

Answer (score 0):

The problem IMHO is that your data coming from the server should  be sorted by OpportunityID. Check if this is true.

Another cause can be in your gridComplete event. Remove this event and see if the grouping is ok.

Comment: I have checked by removing gridComplete event  but the result is same.

Comment: Is the data comming from the sever sorted by the grouping field OpportunityID? Check this. If it is not sorted the grouping will be broken. If the problem persist, please use jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the problem with data or post your server request here.

Comment: Thanks @Tony the problem is because of index property